# Global navigation plan with specific velocities in plan points

Tags: ros, navigation, turtlebot, global-planner, nav-core

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've got a specific task for robot:

Create global navigation plan specifying a set of points with required velocities in this points(x, y, Vx, Vy).

Will I be able to create custom global plan to satisfy this requirement or I need to rewrite the local planner as well?
It seems to me that for now when robot approaches destination its speed slowly decreases to 0, but in my plan it shouldn't, until the robot reaches the last point.

Can this requirement be resolved with existent global nav planners?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172276/global-navigation-plan-with-specific-velocities-in-plan-points/) by [INait](https://answers.ros.org/users/11781/inait/) on ROS Answers with karma: 220 on 2014-05-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you'll have to modify the nav stack pretty significantly to do this. Currently, the nav stack uses a `nav_msgs/Path` to communicate the global plan between the global planner and the local planner, and that message only includes timestamps and positions; no velocity data.

Take a look at the [nav_core wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/nav_core) for more information about the existing planner APIs.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-05-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [INait](https://answers.ros.org/users/11781/inait/) on 2014-05-31**:
Thanks for the answer, I'll check it out.